# Adding visits monitoring to GeoNetwork with Piwik

Tags: javascript, geonetwork

I would like to start monitoring visits to a GeoNetwork instance with [Piwik](https://piwik.org/). This requires the addition of a piece of JavaScript like the one below to each page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _paq = _paq || [];
  /* tracker methods like "setCustomDimension" should be called before "trackPageView" */
  _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
  _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
  (function() {
    var u="//webstats.myserver.org/";
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', '22']);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
  })();
</script>
```

So far I understand I must create a `.js` in the `geonetwork/catalog/js` folder with this code. What I am yet to grasp is then how to include this file into each page served by this instance. Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can paste it in `<head></head>` section in this file: `web-app/src/main/webapp/xslt/base-layout.xsl`.

Comment: I added the code block to the header in that file, but when I load GeoNetwork in the browser that piece is not present. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: I am running this from eclipse and restarting jetty server is enough to show for example another meta tag. Are you using war or install version?

Comment: I needed to restart the instance from tomcat.